# how to make header in web still available when i scroll down?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I make 'close' icon in header of my text, so i want to make the "close" icon still available/ still on there when i scroll down. please help

```
<div class="content">
    <img class="btnclose" src="images/close.png" onclick="showMenuform()">
    <br>
    <br>
    <img src="images/TOEFL.gif" alt="">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="text">
        /**my text**/
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to do some `css` stuff for that. And your question is no where related to `javascript` and `php` . It should be `html` and `css`

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/KevinWang15/pen/jqpoQd

Is this what you're looking for?

1. move `<img>`,`<div>`.. (all the content you want still on) out of the .content div, into a new div
2. set css of the new div to:

   ```
   style="position:fixed;top:0px;right:0px"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

try to write btnclose class out from content class or change btnclose with id instead so you write css for btnclose id too

Comment: i have make banner that i used position in css. now i want the "close" icon available in bottom that banner. so, the banner and close icon was available when i scroll down. now the banner is available but the close icon didnt available

Answer (score -1):

Also, try adding a `display` css property to it.

Comment: can you put it on css script?

Comment: @Kyle1323 please make sure you properly understand the question and that you're fluent in some technology / language before answering questions.